# Exchanging the dependent and independent variable in an ODE as a trick to find the implicit solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While reading Bender and Orszag - Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers (pg. 20, Example 1), I found the following short example which I'll paraphrase:

> The differential equation $y'(x)=x/(x^2 y^2 + y^5)$ is not a Bernoulli equation in $y$, but exchanging the dependent and independent variable gives $x'(y)=(x^2 y^2 + y^5)/x = x y^2 + y^5/x$ which is a Bernoulli equation, with the solution $x(y)=\pm \sqrt{C e^{-2y^3/3}-3/2-y^3}$.

They give a slightly incorrect solution in the text, the solution above should be the correct one. To the best of my understanding, the point of the whole thing is to obtain an implicit solution for $y'(x)$ by instead finding an explicit solution for $x(y)$. Solving the Bernoulli equation is not a problem and since it's relatively straightforward, I've left out the detailed calculations.

The question is, how do you justify doing this switch in the first place:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{x^2 y^2 + y^5} \iff \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2 y^2 + y^5}{x}$$

Furthermore, is this really the solution to the initial DE $y'(x)$? It's relatively easy to confirm it's the solution of $x'(y)$ (if anything using Mathematica's DSolve), but I'm failing to show it solves $y'(x)$ as well, to the point where I'm confused if I misunderstood the whole thing and it's not even supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That switch is justified on a neighborhood of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ where $\frac{dy}{dx} \neq 0$. The justification is the inverse function theorem. It breaks down once you hit a point where $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, at which point $x$ can fail to be a function of $y$ (consider $y'=-x/y$ to get a feel for why this is).